# Roku remote in javascript

Tags: javascript, roku

I am get errors in the web console for my roku remote control script. The javascript is as shown here:

```
  <script>
    function rokuSend(RokuAccess) {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      xhr.onload=function() { alert(xhr.responseText); }
      xhr.open("POST", RokuAccess);
      xhr.send();
    }
    function rokuKeySend(keyVal) {
      rokuSend("http://" + document.getElementById('RokuIP').value + ":8060/keypress/" + keyVal);
    }
```

I supply the IP address for the Roku using:

```
<form id="Roku"><input type="text" id="RokuIP"></form>
```

When ever I press a key on my web based remote it send a command, to simplify things I will be using the SAME function to send key presses as well as other commands. So one of the functions called "**rokuKeySend()**" simply constructs the proper string that is needed to send a command issued by a key press. The second function "**rokuSend()**"sends the command to the Roku. Later additional commands will be sent to collect data from the Roku so I will create more functions that use "**rokuSend()**". For now I use the following buttons (these will later be replaced with images), for now they work fine as proof of concept:

```
<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Back')">Back</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Home')">Home</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Up')">Up</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Left')">Left</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Select')">Select</button></td>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Right')">Right</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Down')">Down</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('InstantReplay')">InstantReplay</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Info')">Info</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Rev')">Rev</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Play')">Play</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Fwd')">Fwd</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Backspace')">Backspace</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Search')">Search</button>

<button type="button" onclick="rokuKeySend('Enter')">Enter</button>
```

After placing the IP into the input of the form, I can press ANY of the buttons and they do work. However they 'visually' depress when clicked by a mouse, but do not return from the depressed state. Upon checking the web console of the browser I found an error. This error is likely the reason I do not get return from the depressed state. How do I fix this? The error is listed below:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/keypress/KEY. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

In the above error 'xxx' represents the IP and 'key' represents the key that was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Its mentioned in the error, CORS Header is missing. **Cross Object Resource Sharing**(CORS) requires to add header "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" in the request. You can try to add this header in the request-

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

If its not working, you have to create something proxy kind of solution. You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and [here](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9) regarding CORS and fixing the error.

Comment: I actually gave up on this because of stuff happening in my life not because I lost interest, I still want to figure this out again and need to recover what I already worked on...

So I wanted to thank Swaran. I will definitely try his answer.